# How can I perform an eqJoin() on a deeply-nested but predictably-placed attribute?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table (db name is `libstats`, table name is `flowcells`) full of documents, all of which have a structure like this:

```
      {
        "barcode": "C3W9UACXX",
        "id": "0021732f-2c42-4e9a-90fd-c68bb0d998dc",
        "lanes": {
            "1": [
                {
                    "bases": 2431000000,
                    "library_id": "SL58263",
                    "perc_raw_clusters": 5.5,
                    "pf_reads": 24312986,
                    "q30": 92.23,
                    "qscore": 35.82,
                    "reads": 25834646
                },
                {
                    "bases": 2121000000,
                    "library_id": "SL58264",
                    "perc_raw_clusters": 4.83,
                    "pf_reads": 21209905,
                    "q30": 91.57,
                    "qscore": 35.62,
                    "reads": 22701386
                }...],
            "2": [
                {
                    "bases": 2431000000,
                    "library_id": "SL58263",
                    "perc_raw_clusters": 5.5,
                    "pf_reads": 24312986,
                    "q30": 92.23,
                    "qscore": 35.82,
                    "reads": 25834646
                },
                {
                    "bases": 2121000000,
                    "library_id": "SL58264",
                    "perc_raw_clusters": 4.83,
                    "pf_reads": 21209905,
                    "q30": 91.57,
                    "qscore": 35.62,
                    "reads": 22701386
                }...],
         },
         //more keys
  }
```

The `lanes` object will always have the same keys (numbers 1 through 8), and the objects in the array associated with each of these keys will always have the `library_id` attribute. I need to add the `library_name` to each of these objects, such that I get a result like this:

{ ...
   "lanes":{
       "1": [
               {
                   "bases": 2121000000,
                   "library_id": "SL58264",
                   "library_name": 'my_library_name',  <---added attribute
                   "perc_raw_clusters": 4.83,
                   "pf_reads": 21209905,
                   "q30": 91.57,
                   "qscore": 35.62,
                   "reads": 22701386
               },
               ...
            ],...
  ...
{

I have another table with the `library_name` attribute (db name `libraries`, table name `libraries`) with a much simpler structure:

```
{
   library_id: 'SL123456',
   library_name: 'my_library_name'
}
```

Is there a RQL query I can use to accomplish this? On simpler tables, [eqJoin()](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq_join/) works beautifully, but I'm having trouble making it work with this more complex structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier if `lanes` were an array rather than an object, but with the current document structure a query like this should do it:

```
r.db('libstats').table('flowcells').merge(function(flowcell) {return {
    'lanes': flowcell('lanes').keys().map(function(n) {
      return r.expr([n, flowcell('lanes')(n).merge(function(lane) {
        {'library_name': r.db('libraries').table('libraries').get(lane('library_id'))}]).coerce_to('OBJECT')})};})
```